# java.io.IOException: 400 error loading URL

Tags: java, android

I'm using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org) to connect a url

the url redirects to another one by 302

I want to get the main url (second one after redirection)

Here is the code:

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup
.connect(f_url[0])
.method(Connection.Method.GET)
.followRedirects(false)
.header("Accept", "image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5")
.header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
.header("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5")
.header("Connection", "keep-alive")
.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0")
.timeout(globalData.WEB_TIME_OUT).execute();
String the_url = response.header("Location");
```

The problem : I get ioexception I'm sure the url is correct its a file for download i have tested it.it redirects to main address and the file starts to download

```
java.io.IOException: 400 error loading URL
```

Comment: Does changing `followRedirects` to `true` change anything?

Comment: 400 means bad request... But I don't see anything wrong here :/

Comment: Yes it raises java.net.SocketTimeoutException thats why i've set followRedirects false the URL is http://laserpeh.ir/milad/redirect_it/Full-Album/Hengameh/Hengameh%20%20Be%20Khatere%20To/Track%20No02.mp3

Comment: Are the spaces in the url the problem?If yes how can i fix it?